# mongodb get sum of value within time period

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to find some records that has created within specific time period.
Then I want to calculate the sum of value of these record.

```
{"member_id":"3755","value":184607,"create_time":"2017-8-11 10:36:58"
{"member_id":"3234","value":74582,"create_time":"2017-8-11 10:36:58",
{"member_id":"4857","value":36776,"create_time":"2017-8-11 10:36:58",
{"member_id":"2042","value":15753,"create_time":"2017-8-11 10:36:58",
{"member_id":"1374","value":655103,"create_time":"2017-8-11 10:36:59"
{"member_id":"3777","value":595437,"create_time":"2017-8-11 10:36:59"
{"member_id":"5271","value":306364,"create_time":"2017-8-11 10:36:59"
{"member_id":"2143","value":164831,"create_time":"2017-8-11 10:36:59"
{"member_id":"1374","value":655103,"create_time":"2017-8-11 10:36:59"
{"member_id":"3777","value":595437,"create_time":"2017-8-11 10:36:59"
{"member_id":"5271","value":306364,"create_time":"2017-8-12 10:36:59"
{"member_id":"2143","value":164831,"create_time":"2017-8-12 11:28:59"
{"member_id":"3777","value":595437,"create_time":"2017-8-12 14:46:59"
{"member_id":"5271","value":306364,"create_time":"2017-8-13 11:36:59"
{"member_id":"2143","value":164831,"create_time":"2017-8-13 13:36:59"
...
```

Here are the code for getting the sum of value, how can I get the sum of value between 2017-8-11 10:36:00 and 2017-8-12 14:00:00

```
  connection.aggregate([{
                $match: match
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    total: {
                        $sum: "$value"
                    }
                }
            }
        ], function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw (err);
            result = {
                member_id: member_id,
                total: result[0].total,
            }
            cb(result);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store date as string. Store it with date format and Try below query

```
 db.connection.aggregate([{
        "$match" : { "create_time" : { "$gt" : new ISODate("2017-08-11T10:36:00.000Z"), "$lt" : new ISODate("2017-08-12T14:00:00.000Z") }},
        "$group" : { "_id": "$member_id", "total": { "$sum": 1 }}
    }])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let todayDate = new Date();
let beforeDate = new Date();
beforeDate.setDate(beforeDate.getDate() - 15); // 15 is days
db.collections.aggregate([
    {
        "$match":
            {
                "insertDate":
                    {
                        "$lte": todayDate,
                        "$gte": beforeDate
                    }
            }
    }
])
.exec()
.then((result) => {
    //result
})
.catch((err) => {
    // error
});
```